# French grammar textbook suitable for "Exercices de grammaire en contexte"

Tags: grammaire, ressources

I have learned French on my own, and used many grammar references from the Internet, and also done all the exercises in the book [Exercices de grammaire en contexte, niveau intermédiare](https://www.amazon.fr/Exercices-grammaire-contexte-niveau-interm%C3%A9diaire/dp/2011551471).

The subjects of exercises in that book are quite familiar, however, I haven't found any grammar textbook compatible with them.

Could you please suggest a textbook that complements the above book?

Comment: Most books I know have both, lessons and exercises. [This editor](https://www.emdl.fr/fle/materiels-complementaires/grammaires/la-grammaire-du-francais) usually has good material, you can have a look, they have a pdf  "unité modèle"  you can download. I expect B1 would be "intermédiaire".

Comment: I like the book *Maîtriser la grammaire française* but I have no idea if that suits that book. Maybe there's something of interest on this list: https://plus.google.com/+BryanDenny/posts/2x97mxTS3Kd

Also, several English speakers have told me they like Schaum's Outline of French Grammar.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe buy a Bescherelle. I used thoses books many times when I was younger.

Here, you will find the references for a box with 4 Bescherelle (conjugaison, grammaire, orthographe, vocabulaire): http://bescherelle.com/le-coffret-bescherelle-9782218992001